# Android 4 startActivityForResult with Intent.ACTION_EDIT always returns resultcode RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

This problem occurs with android version 4.0.3. I am adding contacts with a custom RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE using the Android Contacts 2.0 API. As a second step I want to use Intent.ACTION_EDIT to edit those contacts using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setData(contactUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_CONTACT_RESULT);
```

The Intent is opening up the android built in edit contact activity. But when I press done, it is forwarding me to a contact view activity of the currently edited contact. If I then hit the back button, I get forwarded back to my application. The Problem is that onActivityResult(); always returns RESULT_CANCELED as a result code. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens even on "stock Android" (JB, Galaxy Nexus). It seems the only way around it is to ignore the result code and to reread the contact again regardless of it (note that the Intent data will also be null, so you'd have to the contact Uri you had used when opening the Edit Activity).

Comment: I actually took a long shot and implemented a custom edit contact activity, which suits my needs. It even returns the correct result code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a lot of manufacturers tweak their SDKs, and a lot off apps fail to implement properly this, let call it `"Android Pattern"` where you should return the proper `RESTULT_CODE`. I have also encountered a lot of similar behaviours in the `Facebook`,`Twitter`, etc applications, and even them fail to return a proper result code if the user has shared/ or cancelled the action.

I don't think there is a problem with your code, it is very likely, that the problem is in the application that you are starting, which fails in returning a proper result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have a recommendation on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following solved a similar problem for me:

```
intent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
```